# What is the jQuery keydown response from a Macbook remote control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to use the (awesome) [Deck.js slideware](http://imakewebthings.github.com/deck.js/#sample) using the little white remote control on a MacBook.

You can advance the slide using the arrow keys, or you can override this behaviour to specify your own keys to advance the slides.

```
$.deck('.slide', {
   keys: {
      next:  // numeric keycode for your remote's next button,
      previous: // numeric keycode for previous button 
   }
});
```

How can I determine **the keydown code which the Mac remote is sending** for the next/previous buttons (and is it even sending one)?

I tried testing the remote at http://api.jquery.com/keydown but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

thanks

Comment: It is fairly possible that this control isn't associated with any keycode value.

Comment: I don't think that any browser is set up to receive the signal and interpret the signal from the remote. However, I used to have an application with which you could connect any application with the remote (specifying which keycodes should be sent to the application). Unfortunately I cannot remember the name, but maybe you can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple Remote doesn't produce any keycode values which you can detect.

You need to use an application like [Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/) or [Sofa Control](http://www.caseapps.com/sofacontrol/) to map the buttons on the remote to keypresses.

Comment: Another workaround is to use a PC remote control. I was able to use a Logitech R400, which mapped to keydown codes 33 and 34 without any additional software/hardware